# Define a class with a variable name in PHP?

Tags: php, class, variables, dynamic

I am wanting to be able to do something to the order of this

```
$name = "Hello".time().mt_rand();
class $name {
    function hellolol() {
        echo "LOL";
    }
}
$name::hellolol();
```

So that I can build a reload-able module system in PHP.  Is this even possible, and if so, how would I go about doing something like this?

EDIT:  I've since turned this into a project that essentially does what the accepted answer suggested.  Here's a link:  https://github.com/Modfwango/Modfwango

Comment: Why is that necessary to build a "reload-able module system"? What *is* a "reload-able module system"?

Comment: Are you sure your method name is fixed ;-)

Comment: Since you cannot redefine classes, I need to be able to have a dynamic name for the class.  This will allow me to include a file, initialize the function, and register the classname in a module management class.

Comment: That only makes sense if the method code would also be variant. Else just declare an object with your `$name` variable. Options: `class_alias()`, or `eval()` (not advisable to noobs). Might be sensible to [elaborate on your actual goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) instead.

Comment: I would rather not go through the trouble of having the entire class in a string, methods and all, just to have a dynamic name.  This seems to be too troublesome, not to mention the syntax highlighting wouldn't work in my text editor.

Comment: @ClayFreeman: *Why* do you need a dynamic name, though? Why do you even need separate classes?

Comment: I agree with @minitech - there should be absolutely no reason to have a dynamically named class.

Comment: Yes, there would be.  It would allow for an amazing module system.  It would allow me to be able to reload code without restarting the entire process.

Comment: @ClayFreeman: *Specifically*, how?

Comment: If I can have classes with dynamic names, I could reference a variable to access the class, throw an instantiated version of the class into an array, and use this to reload certain parts of the code, instead of restarting the whole process.

Comment: @ClayFreeman: Sorry, not specific enough :) I really don't see how that changes anything. Do you mean you want to update a file and include it again? (How are you running PHP in such a way that that's even possible?)

Comment: @minitech refer to the answers by Adam and chelmertz below.

Comment: @ClayFreeman: That's still a "how", not a "why". I realize it *can* be done using `eval` - I still don't see why you need to do that. Again: do you mean you want to update a file and include it again? How is the file update going to happen while PHP is still running?

Comment: How would it be easier to update the answers provided below rather than have a single declarative class?

Comment: @minitech I will be making revisions to the files and will issue a command to reload them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$name = "Hello".time().mt_rand();
eval(sprintf('
class %s {
    static function hellolol() {
        echo "LOL";
    }
}', $name));
$name::hellolol();
```

Pretty nasty but good for mocking, etc.

Comment: This should work, and I appreciate the answer, but I am weary that this will show up horribly in my text editor.

Comment: It probably will. Trick it by using a template, place the content in a .php file with the definition `class @@CLASSNAME@@` and use `eval(str_replace('@@CLASSNAME@@', $class_name, file_get_contents('your_template.php')));`

Comment: I am probably going to end up doing that.

Comment: Looks familiar! Keep in mind that `eval` parses the given string as though it's already prefixed by `<?php`, so you'll need to use `eval('?>'.[...]` if the template file starts with `<?php`

Comment: @Adam: did you invent sed as well? ^^ I just saw this eval-method in the wild, check out Kohana2's autoloader. I'm gonna be sick..

Answer (score 3):

This technically *is* possible, just in a very, very bad way.

First, save this file:

```
<?php
// GeneratedClass.php
class CLASSNAME {
    function hellolol(){
        echo "LOL";
    }
}
```

Then, use the following to create classes with custom names:

```
<?php
function generate_class($name){
    eval('?>'.str_replace('CLASSNAME', $name, file_get_contents('GeneratedClass.php')));
}

generate_class("Hello".time().mt_rand());
```

Again, this is **not a good idea!** Aside from the fact that anything to do with `eval` is probably a bad idea, by parsing these classes manually, you'd lose any advantages an IDE would give you, the files wouldn't be cacheable by something like memcached, and it's just altogether a nightmare to use. But it's possible.

Comment: I like this answer.  This may be how I set this up.  I am going to use something to this nature to make a reload-able module system for an IRC bot.  This will allow me to instantiate new classes for commands when they are reloaded so that I won't have to restart the whole process for minor changes to things.

Comment: Hopefully it works for you! A long time ago I had a similar setup to this going to let me override classes throughout an application, or generate a class if the override didn't exist...I've since realised that wasn't a good idea, and come up with better ways to go about it, so make sure it's the best option for what you're trying to achieve!

Comment: I hope this works.  I think that it will work for me.  I will throw away the old classes when they are old, etc.

Comment: If the classes you're generating are going to be used more than once, consider saving them to a file instead of `eval`ing, so then you can `include` them like normal, and save having to reload the original generation file each time.

Comment: Generation will be part of the class for managing the modules that I load.